# How to inject implementations from another module

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm having a project based on Dagger 2 which consists of two modules. The core module includes some interfaces and some classes that have member injections declared for these interfaces.

The actual implementations of these interfaces are included in the second module which is an Android project. So, naturally the provide methods for these are included in the Android project.

Dagger will complain during compilation about not knowing how to inject these in the core module.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this without using constructor injections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, I just tried this, and it works. Be sure to check the exact error messages and make sure you are providing these interfaces and `@Inject` annotations are present.

There is probably just some wrong named interface or a missing annotation. Following up is a full sample using your described architecture that is compiling just fine. The issue you are currently experiencing is probably the one described in the last part of this post. If possible, you should go with the first solution though and just add those annotations.

## The library

For reproducability this sample has minimalist models. First, the interface needed by my class in the library module:

```
public interface MyInterface {
}
```

Here is my class that needs that interface. Make sure to declare it in the constructor and provide the `@Inject` annotation!

```
@MyScope // be sure to add scopes in your class if you use constructor injection!
public class MyClassUsingMyInterface {
    private MyInterface mMyInterface;

    @Inject
    public MyClassUsingMyInterface(MyInterface myInterface) {
        mMyInterface = myInterface;
    }
}
```

The idea is that the interface will be implemented by the app using `MyClassUsingMyInterface` and provided by dagger. The code is nicely decoupled, and my awesome library with not so many features is complete.

## The application

Here need to supply the actual coupling. This means to get `MyClassUsingMyInterface` we have to make sure we can supply `MyInterface`. Let's start with the module supplying that:

```
@Module
public class MyModule {
    
    @Provides
    MyInterface providesMyInterface() {
        return new MyInterface() {
            // my super awesome implementation. MIT license applies.
        };
    }
}
```

And to actually use this, we provide a component that can inject into `MyTestInjectedClass` that is going to need `MyClassUsingMyInterface`.

```
@Component(modules = MyModule.class)
public interface MyComponent {
    
    void inject(MyTestInjectedClass testClass);
}
```

Now we have a way to provide the requested interface. We declared that interface needed by the library class in a constructor marked with `@Inject`. Now I want a class that requires my awesome library class to use. And I want to inject it with dagger.

```
public class MyTestInjectedClass {

    @Inject
    MyClassUsingMyInterface mMyClassUsingMyInterface;

    void onStart() {
        DaggerMyComponent.create().inject(this);
    }
}
```

Now we hit compile...and dagger will create all the factories needed.

### Inject Libraries you can not modify

To just provide the full scale of dagger, this sample could also have been without actual access to the source code of the library. If there is no `@Inject` annotation dagger will have a hard time creating the object. Notice the missing annotation:

```
public class MyClassUsingMyInterface {
    private MyInterface mMyInterface;

    public MyClassUsingMyInterface(MyInterface myInterface) {
        mMyInterface = myInterface;
    }
}
```

In that case we have to manually provide the class. The module would be needed to be modified like the following:

```
@Module
public class MyModule {

    @Provides
    MyInterface providesMyInterface() {
        return new MyInterface() {
        };
    }

    @Provides
    MyClassUsingMyInterface providesMyClass(MyInterface myInterface) {
        return new MyClassUsingMyInterface(myInterface);
    }
}
```

This introduces more code for us to write, but will make those classes available that you can not modify.

Comment: Nice example. Thanks. The issue I'm having with this, is that I want `MyClassUsingMyInterface` to use member injections and not constuctor injections. The reason is that I need to inject a Provider of `MyInterface` to allow the class to get new instances each time it wants and not the same instance. Perhaps there is some other solution I'm not aware of that can work with constructor injections?

Comment: @Nick if you just switch from `MyInterface` to `Provider<MyInterface>` dagger can still inject it without any issues

Comment: Didnt know about that. Thanks.